# .bash_profile not running with multiple commands

Tags: macos, bash

I am having an issue with my `.bash_profile` script.

If I simply have the line

```
source ~/sh/bashmarks.sh
```

the `bashmarks.sh` script runs as expected.

However, if I add an alias

```
source ~/sh/bashmarks.sh
alias gs='git status '
```

I get the message:

```
No such file or directory/bashmarks.sh
```

I should be able to add additional commands after I specify the script correct?  What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a line-endings issue. Make sure your bash file is using UNIX `\n` instead of Windows `\r\n`.

Comment: Indeed it was.  I am learning the Sublime text editor and the default line ending option was set to 'default' which I assumed meant LF.  Changing the setting to 'unix' fixed the issue.